# Creating multiple threads for writing files to Disk, Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, callable

I have an piece of code which writes an object to disk as an when the object is put into the LinkedBlockingQueue.

As of now, this is Single threaded. I need to make it multi threaded as the contents are being written to the different files on disk.and therefore, there is no harm in writing them independently.

I am not sure if i can use ThreadPool here as i dont know when the object will be placed on the queue!! now if i decide to have a fixedThreadPool of 5 threads, how do i distribute it among multiple objects?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
here is my existing code. I want to Spawn a new thread as and when i get a new object in the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`how do i distribute it among multiple objects?`

Well, you don't have to worry about task distribution. All you need to do is submit a runnable or callable(which describes your task) and it will be handed to an idle thread in the pool or if all the threads are busy processing, this new task will wait in queue.

Below is what you can try...

1) Create a thread pool that suits your need best.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(desiredNoOfThreads);
```

2) As you already have the queue in place -

```
while (true) {
    //peek or poll the queue and check for non null value
    //if not null then create a runnable or callable and submit
    //it to the ExecutorService
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tirath for your answer. i am pretty much convinced. just 1 doubt. If i have multiple threads listening to the same queue, will it not create any problem? 2 threads might pick the same object at once!! is this handled by ThreadPool? does Threadpool guarantee that only 1 thread will have access to 1 object on the queue??

Comment: `LinkedBlockingQueue` is a thread safe class. So, no need to worry about multiple threads accessing the same queue. Its all been taken care of.

Comment: I got trapped in another issue here. I created a ThreadPool, threads are listening to LinkedBlockingQueue. now, I have cacheEntrySet which is the object in the queue. this set is also having the name of the file to be written on Disc. If two objects has same file name, it has to write to the same file on the disc.     How do i make sure that 2 threads are not writing to the same file? as it will corrupt my data. how do i assign thread based on the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if your files are on the same physical device you will get no performance benefit since storage devices work synchronously on read/write operations. So your will get your threads blocked on I/O, which can lead to poorer speed, and definitely will waste threads that could be doing useful work.